# FinalBuilder 7. Is it possible to know who broke the build?

Tags: build, build-process, build-automation, finalbuilder

I am pretty new in builders and absolutely newbie in FinalBuilder. 
It is a great app, very intuitive, well documented with lots of features. 
But I can't find one thing:
**How can I determine who is responsible for the broken build?**

Answer (score 2):

This is a notoriously hard problem to tackle, and I'd be surprised if FB server got it right. That's not to say that there isn't any function to get some information out of it, but consider this:

If two commits are done within a short timespan, and the server is currently occupied, by the time it picks up the changes and runs, it will run for the last one. How do you know which of the two changesets are really responsible?

Also, if I remove a method, and you call it, which of the two are in error? Me because I removed the wrong method, or you because you call a method we're not supposed to be using?

TeamCity has some provisions for this, but it frequently gets things wrong, in particular, consider the following sequence of events:

1. Person A checks in something, which breaks the build. Person A gets an email about this.
2. Person B checks in something, build still not running correctly, person B does not get any email
3. Person C checks in something, that by itself would also break the build. Build is, however, still not running, but now only partly because person A still hasn't fixed the problem he introduced.
4. Person A checks in a fix to his problem, build still not running because of person C's change, which still haven't been fixed.

It gets complicated knowing "who broke the build", at most you can figure out who "started a sequence of breaking the build". I know TeamCity gives you that, I don't know if FB server does.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you define "who is responsible for the broken build" If you define it as author of the last commit then you should retrieve the information from source control system. In case of subversion you can use svn info task to get the author.

Comment: Uh you mean svn blame/annotate?

Comment: Finalbuilder comes with an action 'Subversion Info': http://www.finalbuilder.com/version-control-systems.aspx You can use it to get the last author.

Comment: You see the problem is I don't need exactly the last author. When msbuild fails it generates error like that: RDAgent\RDAgentAccess.cs(171): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CompressionResult' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
So I guess I'm gonna need the script that extracts the line number   and using svn blame command gets the user responsible for broken code